# AirFlow scheduler - run date

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that runs weekly on every Monday at 11am. It ran on 13/05, it was turned off on 20/05 and was turned on again on 27/05.

```
dag = DAG(
    'my_dag',
    description='my_desc',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 11 * * 1',
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False)
```

My question is: on 27/05 DAG ran but "run date" was set to 20/05 and I don't know why. Is it because it was turned off on 20/05 and DAG got the "last scheduled date"? In this case, next week (June 3) it will run with "run date" set to 27/05 or 03/06?

What will be *execution_date* and *next_execution_date* in this case on June 3?

[image: Task state]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you watch on all running tasks of current dag, you will see that at `Run` show datetime of previous running task defined in schedule_interval. `Started` and `Ended` show running real datetime of current task.
In the next week (June 3) you will see in `Run` this date `2019-05-27T11:00:00'

Comment: In this case, on June 3 "next execution date" will be June 3 and "execution date" will be May 27? Thanks!

Comment: @brenoriba On June 3 until task isn't run yet

Comment: In this case just to be sure my understanding: on June 3 it will run with <next_execution_date> set to June 3 and <execution_date> set to May 27, right?

Comment: @brenoriba Yes. Read [this](https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/gotchas.html) Best practices for more understand